# Flask-praetorian, not able to pass auth header to protected endpoint

Tags: flask, header, flask-wtforms, flask-praetorian

im using flask-praetorian in order to add security to my app.

I got two routes: one for /login and a protected endpoint called /profile. The Login route works fine, it takes the username and password from the form, im able to pass the information to the guard object and authenticate it to get a new token, but im not been able to pass this token to the request headers for the protected endpoint.
I've tried to use the 'session" to add the header, the 'make_response' method, and the redirect(url_for()), but everytime it gets to the endpoint does it without the correct header causing the error.

Code below:

```py
@user.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
        user = guard.authenticate(username, password)
        token = guard.pack_header_for_user(user)
        resp = make_response(profile())
        resp.headers['Authorization'] = token['Authorization']
        return resp

    else:

        return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@user.route('/profile')
@auth_required
def profile():

    return render_template('profile.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Author of the flask-praetorian package here)

The issue here is that you are just calling the `profile()` method from your `login()` method. Calling `pack_header_for_user` will not actually put the correct auth headers in the current request context. Instead, it just creates a header dict that could be put into a request (but is nicely returned as json). You *could* jam the token into the current request by tinkering with flask's request context, but it would not be the best way.

The right way to do this is to have your `login` route include the token in your response payload and then to make another call from your frontend code to the profile endpoint with the token added to the request header.

Really, I think you would be better off going with a different package like flask-security. The flask-praetorian package is intended to be used with pure APIs, and I haven't done any testing or prototyping with standard flask pages.